# SQL query to select data from either a table or from b table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have 2 tables a and b.

```
Table a
I'd   name

Table b
I'd name address
```

Now I have one name which may be present in either in a table or in b table. So I have to write a single to select the I'd of the person based on name in plsql.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Id, name, address, 'b' as tableName
    FROM b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, name , '', 'a'
    FROM a) dt
WHERE name = yourName;
```

To have aa preview of the result:
[[SQL Fiddle]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae9b2b/2)

You also have name of the table in `tableName` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from table_a where id = <id>
union
select name from table_b where id = <id>
```

or

```
select id from table_a where name = 'john'
union
select id from table_b where name = 'john'
```

This will get you the name from either table a or table b.